# Validating my form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am new to `.Net Framework` and I want to add validations to my windows form application in `Visual Studio 2010 IDE`. I have searched for different ways to do it but I am not sure where can i add that code in my form? One of the example being the code below.

Do I add this code on form load method or on submit button or somewhere else?

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre must be specified")]
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required")]
        [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between $1 and $100")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Rating { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the Use case here. If you want all the validations to appear or act upon while loading of the form, then OnLoad or OnShown events.

Comment: You are trying to implement in ASP.Net MVC way. Check how can be done in windows forms

Comment: I don/t want to use asp.net but a simple implementation using c#.
How can I add validations on text boxes to make sure user enters only alphabets and another text box for phone num that accepts only numbers and '+', '-' from user?

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx and this question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908672/validating-numeric-formats-in-win-forms

Comment: alternatively search for "Win forms validation" and you will get lot of pointers

Comment: Yeah, this looks like MVC.

Comment: is your app web-based or standalone application?

Comment: @Shoban thanks.. This is somewhat useful, although I'm still having some trouble regarding the syntax since I'm a beginner. But thanks for the help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590501/restricting-users-to-input-only-numbers-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: Would FluentValidation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) work for you, assuming you are using MVC?

Comment: No. Firstly I'm not aware of fluent validation so can't comment on it. Moreover I'm not using MVC, its just a code i came across while researching for a useful solution. I wanna use validations in windows form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom `TextBox` with a public property of `ControlType` (like number, Text) and all and then write your implementation for each type. Code sample given below.

```
class CustomTextbox : TextBox
{
    private ControlType _controlType;

    public CustomTextbox()
    {
        Controltype = ControlType.Number;
    }

    public ControlType Controltype
    {
        get { return _controlType; }
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case ControlType.Number:
                    KeyPress += textboxNumberic_KeyPress;
                    MaxLength = 13;
                    break;

                case ControlType.Text:
                    KeyPress += TextboxTextKeyPress;
                    MaxLength = 100;
                    break;
            }
            _controlType = value;
        }
    }

    private void textboxNumberic_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        const char delete = (char)8;
        const char plus = (char)43;
        e.Handled = !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != delete && e.KeyChar != plus;
    }

    private void TextboxTextKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        const char delete = (char)8;
        const char plus = (char)43;
        e.Handled = Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
    }

}

public enum ControlType
{
    Number,
    Text,
}
```

Build your Solution. Pick the newly created control from `Toolbox`. Drag in the form and then change `ControlType` property from `Property Window`. Sample only shows number and text but you can extend things for Phone, email and all.

**Edit**

Can also a default tag in enum which will make it a normal `Textbox`. In this case, dont forget to delink the events.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I could not find ControlType property in property window.

Comment: Build your solution once you are in Form design.

Comment: I already have, but i still cant see it. Can u elaborate as to where exactly in properties?

Comment: Drag the new control in your form. Select the new control. Press F4. ControlType property should be visible then.

Comment: No i cant. :( moreover TextBox namspace could not be found msg is getting displayed when i try to build this class

Comment: can you explain what you are doing exactly......I am able to build and also getting valid things in my form. We can use the chat facility too to discuss

Comment: And I hope you are not making the CustomTextBox in a Library project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25076/discussion-between-ankita-alung-and-rapsalands)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx))

[Here](http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/objectdatasource-and-idataerrorinfo-with-winforms-AID427.aspx) is an example on how you implement it

It goes something like this:

```
public class Movie : IDataErrorInfo
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

  //other properties removed for clearyfication

       private string _lastError = "";

        public string Error
        {
            get { return _lastError; }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get 
            {
               if(columnName == "ID" && ID < 0)
                 _lastError = "Id must be bigger that zero";
            }
        }

}
```